# Setting headers for a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have one jsp page which queries the request header as follows:

```
String ReqValue = request.getHeader("USER");
```

Is there any way I can set this header value before calling the jsp so that when the jsp page is called it gets a valid value when it queries the headers `request.getHeader("USER")`

Comment: I don't think you've understood the http request and http response lifecycle.

Comment: There is no Header named `USER` for a complete list of the possible http headers see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields I think the method you are trying to user would be `String ReqValue = request.getParameter("USER");`

Comment: I think you mean Parameter as Jorge described above or attribute.

Comment: So apart from the method I suggested how to set that header.

Comment: What I'm exactly after is I want to set a header which would be accessible to the server itself. Where do I need to set this and how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default Header named `USER`.  For a complete list of the possible http headers see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

I think the method you are trying to use is

```
String ReqValue = request.getParameter("USER");
```

Comment: You can define any header you want. It doesn't have to be an HTTP standard.